# Playframework 2.1.X - Use a different Build.scala for dev vs. live

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to have a different Build.scala for use in production vs. development? If so what is the recommended strategy to implement this setup? In my use case I'd like to use the play-lessc plugin in development but not use it when pushing live to Heroku.

Comment: Have you had a look at sbt configurations? That may help, not 100% sure though